# TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

Tags: java, maven, exception, junit, surefire

When upgrading from Surefire 2.6 to Surefire 2.13, I get a `TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy` when running my unit tests.

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:653)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:460)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:222)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3070)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3029)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.isValidJUnit4Test(JUnit4TestChecker.java:64)
```

In `JUnit4TestChecker`, line 64 looks like this:

```java
Annotation runWithAnnotation = testClass.getAnnotation( runWith );
```

So Surefire inspects the `@RunWith` annotation to make sure its type is valid. Our tests use Spring, so `@RunWith` looks like this in our test classes:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

It seems like Surefire isn't finding the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` class. I'm not sure why since under Surefire 2.6, the tests run fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Can you please create a [bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE) if there isn't one already.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll try to create a new, simpler project that demonstrates the same issue. Then open a bug report.

Comment: Have you checked newer version cause in the meantime we are at 2.18.1 ?

Comment: Please post the versions of Java, Maven and Spring you are using and your configuration of the `maven-surefire-plugin`.

Comment: Sounds to me like it's RunWith that can't be found.  Is it possible you have two versions of Surefire running in the same classloader?  Is one of your dependencies loading a different version?  This looks a lot like the sort of problem you might encounter when attempting to load two different versions of the same class.

Comment: I had the same exception when the annotation parameter (SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class in this case) was not on my classpath.

Answer (score 2):

Run mvn dependency:resolve

Exclude any 3.x version of JUnit that may have crept in.

Make sure there are no TestNG dependencies, if there are it will load TestNG annotations and not the JUnit ones you need.