# Spring Boot Test java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-test

I am trying to develop an ReST API application with Spring. This application has a multi-module structure, and is separated into 4 modules:

1. Module 1: Application (it only finds all the imports of the other projects and in main for Spring)
2. Model 2: Security configuration (here is everything related to JWT and role security etc.
3. Module 3: Service (In this project I have the models, repositories and handles)
4. Module 4: Endpoint (Here are all the controllers)

The application works perfectly, but I want to be able to add testing classes to improve quality and efficiency, but I'm just trying and in all ways and I find nothing but obstacles. Currently, I have a very simple Testing class (it has nothing), it is in Module 1

```
@SpringBootTest
public class EarRestfulServiceApplicationTest {
    @Test
    public void loadContext() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({SecurityConfig.class, JwtSecurityConfigurer.class, DataJpaConfig.class, JwtProperties.class})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.github.apolalca.earrestfulservice")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.github.apolalca.earrestfulservice")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.github.apolalca.earrestfulservice")
public class EarRestfulServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EarRestfulServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

but when executing the class I get the following error

```
2021-02-20 18:15:51.181  INFO 73772 --- [    Test worker] c.g.a.e.EarRestfulServiceApplicationTest : Starting EarRestfulServiceApplicationTest using Java 1.8.0_231 on MacBook-Pro-de-Adrian.local with PID 73772 (started by adripol94 in /Users/adripol94/dev/Java/ear-restful-service/restful-application)
2021-02-20 18:15:51.182 DEBUG 73772 --- [    Test worker] c.g.a.e.EarRestfulServiceApplicationTest : Running with Spring Boot v2.4.1, Spring v5.3.2
2021-02-20 18:15:51.183  INFO 73772 --- [    Test worker] c.g.a.e.EarRestfulServiceApplicationTest : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-02-20 18:15:51.511 ERROR 73772 --- [    Test worker] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Class.java:3477) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationsScanner.java:454) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.isKnownEmpty(AnnotationsScanner.java:492) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.from(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:251) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations.from(MergedAnnotations.java:351) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations.from(MergedAnnotations.java:330) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.<init>(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:86) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.from(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:175) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotationMetadata.introspect(AnnotationMetadata.java:127) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.<init>(AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.java:58) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.doRegisterBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:253) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:147) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:137) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:168) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:136) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:700) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:122) [spring-boot-test-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) [spring-test-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) [spring-test-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123) [spring-test-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) [spring-test-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) [spring-test-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) [spring-test-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:137) [spring-test-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_231]

2021-02-20 18:15:51.518 ERROR 73772 --- [    Test worker] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@4fb0492b] to prepare test instance [com.github.apolalca.earrestfulservice.EarRestfulServiceApplicationTest@c9fb4cb]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

All `build.gradle` files have a testImplementation for every implementation that exists (just in case it was that). Is it possible that Spring Test is not compatible with multi module project? How can I correctly test the classes? I've thought with Mockito but there are so many layers and services that I think it's going to be hell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656543/typenotpresentexceptionproxy)

Comment: I'm just using dependency 'org.springframework.boot: spring-boot-starter-test'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I cleaned the project, the problem solved. If you use STS or Eclipse IDE, clean it through opening context menu on the project or on the main module and choose Maven > Update Project